# Redefining table caption size on a custom class

Tags: tables, resize

I'm writing a custom latex class and I must to define the size of table captions. Tables captions must to have 6 points of size. I don't know the best way to do it. Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at the `caption` package and its `\captionsetup`?

Comment: I've seen it. However, I've not found out how to set a size of 6 points specifically.

Comment: `\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\selectfont`?

Comment: I assume, that you talk about font size ...

Comment: Excuse me by my newbie question, but what does the second \fontsize parameter stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. As suggested, I've tried the command

```
\captionsetup[table]{\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\selectfont}
```

But, what that effectively worked for me was

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{CaptionFontSize}{\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\selectfont}
\captionsetup[table]{font=CaptionFontSize}
```

Comment: That was the suggested way. We always assume that you are able to read documentations.

Comment: @TeXnician: Stay here for some while and you **don't** assume that users read the documentation really ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- sad but true.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, it's sad.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just assumed the ability...

Comment: @TeXnician: Darth Vader would say: 'Don't underestimate the laziness of users' ;-)